# Django Can't Find Installed App

Tags: python, django

I have my directory structure like this for my Django application:

```
project
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    ...
users
    __init__.py
    model.py
    ....
```

In my model.py I have this class:

```
class User():
    ...
```

However when I configure my INSTALLED_APPS like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
    'users'
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Django cannot find the application users. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is your manage.py? What is the contents of your PythonPath?

Answer (score 4):

Change `model.py` to `models.py`, or if you want to use a different name for your module append the `app_label` argument to your models Meta classes:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    # fields...

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'users'
```